# Sitecore Scheduled Tasks are always not due

Tags: sitecore, scheduled-tasks, sitecore8

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 150121), and I set up a couple of scheduled tasks to populate items last week,

After checking the logs for the past few days it turns out that Sitecore keeps seeing them as not due yet.
Given the fact that I set the schedule to the following

20140101|99990101|127|24:00:00

Comment: You've set the schedule to run every 24 hours, if IIS is reset or the app pool is recycled that resets the counter. If your site has restarted for any reason (e.g. deployments) then that may explain why the schedule is not run.

Comment: The client want's it to run once every night, so the 24 hour schedule is not my choice, is there a workaround?

Comment: I suggest looking at the [Sitecron module](http://www.akshaysura.com/2015/06/23/sitecron-sitecore-module-for-your-everyday-scheduling-needs/), it will allow for more robust scheduling.

Comment: Also make sure that your keepalive service is running properly.
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/376036

Comment: Thanks jammykam and IsNull, I can't add any modules at the time being, and I made sure that the keepalive service is running properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the interval at which sitecore check for due tasks, You can do that by updating the `<scheduling>` section in sitecore settings in web.config also you may consider the following instead : 20140101|99990101|127|23:59:59

Comment: Whats the difference between this and 24 hours setting that is currently set?

Comment: I just recalled there may be an issue [with the setting](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/all-about-sitecore-scheduling-agents-and-tasks.aspx): `Note: The Taks Scheduling (sic) thread on the Sitecore Developer Network (SDN) forums indicates that Sitecore may interpret 24:00:00 as 00:00:00; use a value such as 23:59:59 instead.` so that is in fact correct.